# check if input matches with ip format?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, ip-address

That's how I try to do it.

```
read -p "enter ip " ip 
if [[ $ip =~ ^[1-255].[1-255].[1-255].[1-255]$ ]]; then echo "good"; fi
```

Only work if the input is 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

`[1-255]` means 1 or 2 or 5 , it won't match 1 to 255

use this instead, here I am counting occurrences

```
echo $ip | egrep -o '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

`[0-9]{1,3}\.` means digit 0-9 can comes three times followed by dot

`([0-9]{1,3}\.){1,3}` means above pattern has to be three times

and yup , it will match incorrect IPs too.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly and thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Note this regexp allow for IP like `345.456.567.678` have a look at dupplicate.